# RHEL vagrantbox (or alternative)

Tags: jboss, vagrant, redhat

I've been searching for vagrant box for RedHat linux for a week ended up to nothing. Possibly because RedHat, especially the Enterprise Linux, is under commercial used rather than open-sourced.

I've been trying to learn my ways around JBoss with a RedHat Enterprise Linux distribution via Vagrant. Is there a box already present or should I result to alternative box then install and configure JBoss almost similar with RHEL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed RHEL is not distributed, you need to register with Red Hat to get access to their distribution.

You can use another [Red Hat based distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions#RHEL-based) and it will work almost the same.

the most famous are probably centos as well as Oracle Linux.

You can find those boxes on :

- vagrant atlas : https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&sort=&provider=&q=centos
- http://www.vagrantbox.es/ has a few boxes that match your need

Comment: Thanks. Which between CentOS or Oracle Linux runs similar with RHEL? How about for JBoss?

Comment: both aims to be fully compatible with rhel, there will no different for use with Jboss and specially in scope of learning